# How to optimize writing to histogram in OpenCL (scatter/gather)?

Tags: performance, memory, opencl, histogram

I'm writing something akin to a particle system in OpenCL. All particles have a position and a colour, which is calculated on the fly. At the end of all the calculations, I want to show all the particles on the screen. For this, I want to add all the particle values (many millions of them) to a 2D histogram, so the histogram is large (say 1920*1080).

[image]
*Note that all components, including the alpha-component, are simply summed.*

Currently I simply use a buffer consisting of uint4 (or float4) for this, which is a (huge) bottleneck in my application, as it is a scatter/gather operation to the global memory:

```
//Obviously hugely simplified for your reading pleasure
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    float calculatedYPixel = random() * 1080;
    float calculatedXPixel = random() * 1920;
    uint4 calculatedColour = (uint4) (0, 27, 244, 55); //something random as well
    histogram[(int) calculatedYPixel * histogramSize.x + (int) calculatedXPixel] += calculatedColour;
}
```

Is there any way this could be sped up? I'm currently using OpenCL 1.2, but I would also be interested to hear of solutions involving OpenCL 2, CUDA or OpenGL.

- All particles can end up over the entire area of the histogram, so any type of tiling/organised access is out of the question.
- I don't mind losing a couple particles in the histogram (e.g. updates overwriting each other), speed is far more important.

*I was also curious if the ROP (render output units) could be of any use here, as their function seems pretty similar this type of calculation. From some sources it seems as if the render buffer on a GPU might be optimised for write access for example.*

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way this could be sped up?

As so often, "how do we implement this serial algorithm on a GPU?" is probably the wrong question here. You need to take a step back and think about *what parallel algorithms might give the same result as your serial algorithm*.

The code you posted is probably not particularly close to the actual code you have in mind. But if I was trying to fill a space with random particles according to some distribution, instead of creating particles one by one and randomly generating their locations individually, I would look at each location and generate a random sample for it based on the distribution function.

So essentially, turn a "push" algorithm into a "pull" algorithm.

This gets a lot more difficult if you actually have a good reason for tracking individual particles, but we haven't been given enough information here really.

> I was also curious if the ROP (render output units) could be of any use here, as their function seems pretty similar this type of calculation. From some sources it seems as if the render buffer on a GPU might be optimised for write access for example.

Yes, this is definitely worth exploring if you must stick with the "push" approach, as it sounds like additive blending is basically what you want. In addition to the blending operations, the stencil buffer may also be of interest. You may wish to look into rendering "point sprites" which are supported by all the major 3D APIs - rendering individual pixels isn't something that 3D apps typically do, and thus not necessarily something that GPUs and their drivers are optimised for, but point sprites are basically intended for drawing particle systems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, a "push" algorithm is the only feasible approach here. Hence the comparison with a particle system, where one would also have to track every individual particle to calculate their positions in space, after which they can be written to the screen (although one could try to do some clever space partitioning in that case).

Comment: Additive blending is indeed what I'm looking for (for the alpha-channel too, as mentioned), but how would I address the ROPs from OpenCL, either implicitly or explicitly? Also, point sprites seem to be meant for, well, sprites, whereas in my case each "particle" can only affect a single pixel.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of using the ROPs from OpenCL, not even via an extension. You'll need to use OpenGL/Vulkan/Direct3D/Metal to access those features. Point sprites don't have to be textured, and they certainly can have a size of 1 pixel. Note that OpenCL implementations typically support exchanging buffers with OpenGL and Direct3D or other OS-specific GPU-based image buffer objects, so you don't necessarily need to move other existing code to a different API.